# How to make the sub report data go to next when the first page is filled in Acumatica Report Designer in PDF view

Tags: acumatica

Following are steps done
Placed the sub report in the group section and kept the page break before and after. 
we tried by using keep Together as false for the sub report group  as well

[image]

HTML View 
[image]

PDF View
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you please add the pdf view of this report? Also what is the content of the subreport?

Comment: The Content of the sub report is default Print Pick List report which is there in Acumatica. Can you please help me to figure it out .

Answer (score 0):

Below is the configuration which is working for me.

[image]

You can find the example of the report by this [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1m4tywdj7An_yZQfE9LGiwwVIqMgM1auP)

[image]

[image]